# How to check equality between cells in table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a n-column table with m-rows. I want to check equality between each cell in a row. 
My idea is to store each value in two dimensional array and run 'for loop' to check if values as equal but I think that solution is not efficient. Also I am storing the cell values with nth-child selector and put them into the temporary array. Does anyone know more faster and easier solution? I need to compare m-values of each column and if the values are different the row should be removed from the table.

For example:

[image]

And after running the "check differences" function the result should be:

[image]

Table is built with div's

```
<div class="provider">
    <div class="row">1000</div>
    <div class="row">1500</div>
    <div class="row">1120</div>
</div>
<div class="provider">
    <div class="row">1000</div>
    <div class="row">1200</div>
    <div class="row">1120</div>
</div>
<div class="provider">
    <div class="row">2200</div>
    <div class="row">1700</div>
    <div class="row">1120</div>
</div>
<div class="provider">
    <div class="row">3700</div>
    <div class="row">3300</div>
    <div class="row">1120</div>
</div>
```

And the part of js:

```
for(j = 0; j < rowsCounter; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < colsCounter; i++) {
        buf[j][i] = $('.provider:nth-child(' + i + ') div:nth-child(' + j + ')').text();
    }
}
```

Next part is almost same but running the buf array and checking equality of values..

Comment: `nth-child selector` is slow, just store a direct reference to them. Using the loop is probably fine unless you encounter really huge tables. Please post the working code you already have if you want opinions on its performance.

Comment: Why isn't your Table built with a <table>?

Comment: That html is distinctly odd. Why can't you use a table? Also is that 4 columns with 3 rows or 3 columns with 4 rows?

Comment: It's 4 columns with 3 rows. I think it does not make any difference if I am using table or divs. I'm just wondering how to check the equality between the cells in each row of the table, what is the best way to do that - the fastest way.

Comment: Maybe something like running the loop and checking previous value - if is not equal just break the loop and move to next one? If they are not equal remove the row?

Comment: That's the pseudocode I went with.. There might be a cleaner way, but I don't think the performance of this should be too bad, unless you have A LOT of div.provider

Comment: Your comparison would be much easier if all of the data that was being compared were grouped together . . . is it possible to store the data by row instead of by column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a more scalable approach, you can use something like this:

```
var buf=[];

$('.provider').each(function(){
    var rows=[];
    $('.row', this).each(function(){
        rows.push( parseInt( $(this).text().trim() ));
    });
    buf.push(rows);
});
```

Ideally, you should never suppose that "all children" or "all something somewhere" are part of the elements you want to handle. The best is to be aware of what exact elements you need. In that case, all `.row` that are nested in `.provider`.

Take a look at this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CYNtb/2/).

Comment: `$(this, '.row')` is mixed up.

Comment: i've used your solution to get the values of each cell and then i run next loop to check the equality of them, fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CYNtb/3/

Comment: I'm happy to know that it helped! :-) Taking a look at your loop, I can't keep myself from giving a little advise: While using the `break` statement in a loop can simplify some algorithms, it also breaks its integrity. A `for` is suggesting that you know exactly **how many** iterations are needed. After then, the `break` says "finally I was wrong, I didn't know at all". Using a `while` in those cases instead of a "broken `for`" will save your life one day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's `each()` and `children()` function to loop through your `div.provider` and `.rows`.

Then use a variable to store the `text()` and compare the text with each iteration. If the iteration doesn't match, remove the `parent()`

```
var text;

$('div.provider').each(function() {
    text = '';
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        if (text === '') {
            text = $row.text();
        }
        if (text !== $row.text()) {
            $row.parent().remove();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/D6tam/)

Comment: His data is stored by column right now, not by row . . . with the current setup, he needs to compare the 1st `<div>` of each `$('div.provider')` with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child`-selector is quite slow and extremely inefficient if used like that. Change that snippet to

```
$(".provider").each(function(j) {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        buf[i][j] = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

> Next part is almost same

I can hardly believe that. If it really is, you can do similar improvements.